# The space of valuations of a function field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, valuation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Hello, I'm looking for someone who can help me to understand Zariski's theory of valuations.

First I outline the theory: we take a field $K$ which is a finitely generated transcendent extension of another field $k$. We only consider the case $k=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. By definition, A *model* of $K$ is a variety $V\subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ defined over $k$, such that the rational function field of $V$ over $k$ is isomorphic to $K$. We define the *underlying topological space* of $V$ to be a space, whose points are irreducible subvarieties of $V$, endowed with Zariski topology.

Now comes the interesting thing: Zariski gave an homeomorphism between the space of valuations on $K/k$ and the inverse limit of underlying topological spaces of all models of $K$.

**Question:** Plz give me some concret examples of the above correspondence.

The only example I know is that, given an irreducible hypersurface of a model $V$, one can count the order of rational functions on $V$ over the hypersurface. This gives a discret rank one valuation.

Is there some other easily-described points in the inverse limit, whose corresponding valuations are non-discret, or of higher rank?

Other comments are welcome!

Comment: Easiest example: a complex curve. Every valuation is discrete of rank one, the Zariski-Riemann space is homeomorphic to *the* smooth model of C. This is the motivating example (no inverse limit needed, and well known before Zariski). 
First "interesting" case: surfaces. As an example, if p is a point of the curve C on S, a rank 2 valuation of K(S) counts order on C and intersection with C at p. The corresponding point in the Zariski-Riemann space is the limit of all points on C infinitely near to p. References: Zariski-Samuel "Commutative Algebra", Casas-Alvero "Singularities of plane curves".

Comment: @quim:  Thanks. As I could not find this example in Zariski-Samuel, can you give some details?  I don't understand the meaning of counting "intersection with C at p", and  "limit of all points on C infinitely near to p".

Comment: I'll put several remarks in separate comments. First, the definition of that valuation: assume C is defined near p by x=0 for some $x\in {\mathcal O}_{S,p}$. Every $f\in {\mathcal O}_{S,p}$ can be written uniquely as $x^v⋅\tilde f$ with $v$ a nonnegative integer and $\tilde f$ not divisible by $x$ ($v$ is the order of $f$ over $C$). Now the map $f\mapsto (v,I_p(C,\tilde f))$ is a rank 2 valuation.

Comment: Second, the intersection index $I_p(C,\tilde f)$ can be defined in various ways. One often found is as $\dim {\mathcal O}_{S,p}/(f,x)$. 


Comment: But, third! $C$ can be parameterized locally (analytically) by Puiseux series. That is, if $y,z\in {\mathcal O}_{S,p}$ are local coordinates at $p$ (equivalently, $y,z$ generate the maximal ideal at $p$) then there exist an integer $n$ and a series $h(t)$ such that $t\mapsto (t^n, h(t))$ is a parameterization of $C$ (i.e., the kernel of the map ${\mathcal O}_{S,p}\rightarrow {\mathbb C}[[t]]$ given by $y\mapsto t^n$, $z\mapsto h(t)$ is the ideal generated by $x$. Then, $I_p(C,\tilde f)$ can also be defined as the order (in t) of the image of $\tilde f$ in ${\mathbb C}[[t]]$.

Comment: Ouch, I now realize I should have said from the beginning that $C$ must be unibranch at $p$ (ie, analitically irreducible; this is always the case if $C$ is irreducible).

Comment: Fourth, seen this way, the rank 2 valuation defined above is a particular case of Zariski-Samuel, "Commutative Algebra II", VI.15, example 2, second paragraph.

Comment: Fifth and last. I assume you know what the center of a valuation is in Zariski-Samuel. In this case, the center is (the maximal ideal of) the point $p$. Blow up this point on the surface $S$, obtaining a new model $\tilde S$ for the same field, and let $\tilde C$ be the strict (birational) transform of $C$ on $\tilde S$. Because $C$ is unibranch at $p$, there is a unique point $\tilde p$ on $\tilde C$ whose image by the blowup is $p$ (i.e., infinitely near to $p$). It turns out that (the maximal ideal of) $\tilde p$ is the center in this model of the valuation defined above. Iterate.

Comment: If you start with an arbitrary valuation on a surface, either its center is an irreducible curve, and then you have a discrete rank one valuation, or it is a point. In the second case, blow up the point to get a new model and look for the center there. If it is an irreducible curve, then you have a discrete rank one valuation, otherwise it is a point. Iterating, either you end up with a curve center (so called "divisorial valuations") or you get an infinite sequence of points, determining a point in the Zariski-Riemann space.

Comment: The details and classification of valuations on surfaces according to their sequences of centers is written in Casas-Alvero, "Singularities of plane curves", Chapter8. BTW, I assumed in the "coordinates" part that the surface is smooth at $p$, of course this is not really restrictive.

Comment: Thank you! Concerning the fifth remark, can we say that an irreducible curve passing through $p$ is completely determined by its intersection with the exceptional divisor every time when we blow up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put (more or less already said above). Let $K=C(x,y)$ and let $xi(t)$ be a generalized power series (a power series with well-ordered exponents) where the exponents are non-negative real numbers. Assume (this is important) that $P(t,\xi(t))\neq 0$ for any $P\in K$. Then the map: $\nu(P(x,y))=ord_{t}(t,\xi(t))$ is a valuation (the "order of contact of P with $(t,\xi(t))$").

Notice that if $\xi(t)=t^{\pi}$, for example, the valuation has rational rank $2$. If $\xi(t)$ corresponds to an analytic branch of a curve (non-algebraic), the valuation has rational rank $1$, etc.

By the way, [here](http://books.google.es/books?id=su_4FI26xbkC&pg=PA104&lpg=PA104&dq=valuation+projective+limit+favre&source=bl&ots=ySTFyYb9wa&sig=AaEjpnVGw-n7lE_sf3BkShPQmaI&hl=en&ei=k6N4To3gDYex8QO6_qTBDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) you may find something useful. That book may be of help.

You should read something about point blowing-ups and then you understand the projective limit thing. But without it, it gets somewhat too algebraic.